# Green nut plant Los Angeles CA

Tags: nut-trees

I cant figure out what type of plant this is. Its shell starts to fall around the fall. [image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

"Pachira aquatica" otherwise known as Malabar Chestnut. A tropical tree that grows in swamps in South America. They are edible, however the tree has some propensity for invasiveness.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Picture number 4 looks a lot like Pokeweed: *[Phytolacca americana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phytolacca_americana)*.
It's a separate plant from the tree, correct?